# Как сделать "желейный" эффект(Unity 2D)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите пожалуйста, уже сломал голову. Есть игра - https://www.addictinggames.com/puzzle-games/gluey-game.jsp

Посмотрите на механику слаймов в игре, мне очень нужно сделать как там, что бы было как желе, нашел как сделать так в 3D, но про 2D версию ничего.

Comment: Покажи свои попытки. Что ты уже сделал?

Comment: Softbody желе по туториалу, потом понял что по 2d ничего нету, вот и зашел на стак

Comment: по запросу "unity 2d softbody" первый же линк на видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCGVxMqHYUk  и под ним есть ссылка на гитхаб

Comment: Что сложного 3д сузить до 2д?

Comment: как ты себе это представляешь, для тебя 3d это просто еще одна ось Z?

Comment: Andrew, это видео первое посмотрел, немножко не то что нужно

Comment: @ВаняБадалов расскажу секрет: да, 3d пространство отличается от 2d пространства одной дополнительной осью

Comment: https://github.com/kwanchangnim/Jello-Physics первая страница гугла